# Prevent bold font on kendo multi select dropdown

Tags: visual-studio, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have Kendo multiselect dropdown in my application, and the font is taken as bold automatically.

> When checked with developer tools it is taking some span style tag which
>   is having **font-weight:bold on the text.**

Please anyone help me out to remove bold for the text???

Comment: Can you post an dojo/fiddle showing the problem?  The Kendo MultiSelect demos do not show bold text in the dropdown(neither to do my uses).  What CSS rule is the bold coming from? Is it a Kendo rule or is one of your own rules affecting it?

Comment: this is what i am having in my cs.html file
 `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <select id="target" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select   Target" type="text" value=""></select>
        </div>`
When checked in browser developer tools

Comment: `<select id="target" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect-picker" data-placeholder="Select Target" type="text" value="" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;"></select>
<span style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 18.34px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;">Select Target</span>`